# Disable and enable textbox for edit and save information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this form i try when i click the button edit the input field will be enable and i can edit the information on it

And when i click the save button the input field will be saved on mysql database and the text field will be disabled

i try with this code below but it didn't work

any suggestion please?

```
<form name='' id='' action='' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='txt_category' id='category' value='$category' disabled>
<input type='text' name='txt_stage' id='stage' value='$stage' disabled>
<input type='checkbox' name='txt_approve' id='approve' value='$approve' disabled>
<input type='submit' name='edit' value='edit' onclick='myFunction()'>
<input type='submit' name='save' value='save' onclick='mysaveFunction()'>
</form>
```

/***********************************/

```
<script>
function myFunction() {   
document.getElementById('category').readOnly = true;
document.getElementById('stage').readOnly = true;
document.getElementById('approve').readOnly = true;
}
</script>
```

/**********************************/

```
 <script>
    function mysaveFunction() {   
    document.getElementById('category').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('stage').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('approve').disabled = true;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: you need to elaborate `but it didn't work`. What did you try to do and what did not work ? Update your question so people here can focus on particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("form input[type=text],form input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled",true);

     $("input[name=edit]").on("click",function(){

             $("input[type=text],input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("disabled");
     })

     $("input[name=save]").on("click",function(){

         $("input[type=text],input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled",true);
     })


 })
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form name='' id='' action='' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='txt_category' id='category' value='$category' disabled>
        <input type='text' name='txt_stage' id='stage' value='$stage' disabled>
        <select disabled>
            <option>I am Option 1</option>
             <option>I am Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <input type='checkbox' name='txt_approve' id='approve' value='$approve' disabled>
        <input type="button" name='edit' value='edit'>
        <input type="button" name='save' value='save'>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
     $(document).ready(function(){

         $("form input[type=text],form input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled",true);

         $("input[name=edit]").on("click",function(){

                 $("input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],select").removeAttr("disabled");
         })

         $("input[name=save]").on("click",function(){

             $("input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],select").prop("disabled",true);
         })


     })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want use it in table ,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form name='' id='' action='' method='post'>
        
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' name='txt_category' id='category' value='$category' disabled>
                    <input type='text' name='txt_stage' id='stage' value='$stage' disabled>
                    <select disabled>
                        <option>I am Option 1</option>
                         <option>I am Option 2</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='txt_approve' id='approve' value='$approve' disabled>
                    <input type="button" name='edit' value='edit'>
                    <input type="button" name='save' value='save'>
                </td>
            
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' name='txt_category' id='category' value='$category' disabled>
                    <input type='text' name='txt_stage' id='stage' value='$stage' disabled>
                    <select disabled>
                        <option>I am Option 1</option>
                         <option>I am Option 2</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='txt_approve' id='approve' value='$approve' disabled>
                    <input type="button" name='edit' value='edit'>
                    <input type="button" name='save' value='save'>
                </td>
            
            </tr>
        
        </table>
    
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
     $(document).ready(function(){

         $("form input[type=text],form input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled",true);

         $("input[name=edit]").on("click",function(){

             $(this).closest("td").find("input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],select").removeAttr("disabled");
         })

         $("input[name=save]").on("click",function(){

            $(this).closest("td").find("input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],select").prop("disabled",true);
         })


     })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what should i add for a select field in the jquery to be enabled and disabled ?

Comment: @mhmd , use `select` tag for example , for disabled `$("input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],select").removeAttr("disabled");` and enable `$("input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],select").prop("disabled",true);`

Comment: i put it like this but it doesn't work $(document).ready(function(){
$("form input[type=text],form input[type=checkbox],select").prop("disabled",true);
 $("input[name=edit]").on("click",function(){
$("input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],select]").removeAttr("disabled";})
$("input[name=save]").on("click",function(){  $("input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],select").prop("disabled",true);})})

Comment: thank you i want to ask you i put this with a php code he print a table and each row will have the same input field with 2 buttons edit and save how can i edit the code to when i click edit only the one row will be enabled  to edit the info and when i click the save button to this row only the info of this row will be updated in the database

Comment: how can i update info to mysql database when i click save when i click save the info will be updated and the text field will be disabled ??

Comment: ask this question in tag php,i am expert in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that will answer your question but if you want your inputs to be enabled/disabled on click, you might want to use this :

```
<input type='button' name='edit' value='edit' onclick='myFunction()'>


<script>
function myFunction() {   
    document.getElementById('category').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('stage').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('approve').disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

As a submit input will reload your page, there is no need to disable your input again, this is also why you can't use a `submit` input for your edit button.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the example here. Use .disabled property in both functions:

```js
function mysaveFunction() {   
    document.getElementById('category').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('stage').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('approve').disabled = true;
    }
function myFunction() {   
document.getElementById('category').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('stage').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('approve').disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<form name='' id='' action='' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='txt_category' id='category' value='$category' disabled>
<input type='text' name='txt_stage' id='stage' value='$stage' disabled>
<input type='checkbox' name='txt_approve' id='approve' value='$approve' disabled>
<input type='button' name='edit' value='edit' onclick='myFunction()'>
<input type='submit' name='save' value='save' onclick='mysaveFunction()'>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you but i have a problem when i click edit the input be enabled but the page reload and the input field redisabled again

Comment: The input type for edit should be type='button'. I have updated the example. The type='submit' causes the page to reload.